# “They have to yet scooped it out.”

Tags: phrase-request, phrasal-verbs

> They have to yet scooped it out.

The source is actually me.  Could you correct any grammatical errors you spot?

My perception: There are still some quantity of the good available, even though many people rushed to Bazaars and markets to purchase it.

I noticed *Longman* has an example for using *scoop* this way:

> if a lot of people scoop something up, they buy it quickly so that soon there is none left.

Comment: Unfortunately, your sentence is ungrammatical. Please check the source, and please make sure your understanding refers to the sentence you're referring to.

Comment: _They haven't scooped it out yet_ sounds like something someone might say at a place where you buy ice cream. "I know I ordered a strawberry ice cream cone, but I can I change that to black raspberry?" Answer: _Sure, they haven't scooped it out yet._

Comment: @J.R. - Or the litter box...

Comment: Thank you so much.  Thanks for your recommendations but I wanted to say something like this : They have yet to scoop it up.  Is my interpretation now correct?  There are still some of the goods available to perchace though many people have rushed to markets to buy that.

Comment: _Scoop (up)_ is a verb I'd reserve for an individual. "Did you get a new Xbox yet?" "No, I've yet to **scoop mine up**." However, if I'm asking if there are still some available at the store: "Is it too late to buy a new Xbox?" a friend might reply, "No, it's not too late – they have **not yet sold out**."

Comment: Dear J-R.  My perception of your comment is that my example is not what a native speaks perhaps. But I still have my doubts if the meaning of that is the same as what you suggested. Of course your seggestion is perfectly corret. Just out of curiosity , do they mean the same? ... They (refering to people) have yet to scooped it ( Xbox) out / They ( this time refering to Xbox)  have not yet sold out. .......  definition of scoop up from Longman: if a lot of people scoop something up, they buy it quickly so that soon there is none left. My second and more important concern is that I would be real

Comment: My second concern is that I would be greatful if you clarify what you mean by saying: "I woukd reserve for an individual"   and saying" I have yet to scoop mine up  Does it mean " my old xbox still works" ???

Comment: In the future, you might want to include definitions in your question. Now that I read Longman's definition, I have a better idea of what you're asking. I took the liberty of editing this question, and I've provided an answer which I hope will explain this issue more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb *scoop* means to buy something quickly. It might be used around Christmastime, in conjunction with a item that is selling fast:

> People are scooping up these Xboxes like crazy!

Now, let's take a look at your sentence:

> They have to yet scooped it out.

That's not quite right. I think what you're trying to express is:

> A lot of people are scooping these up, but the store hasn't sold out yet.

People scoop **up** items, but stores sell **out** of items. And the scooping can start well before the sellout happens. Think about tickets to a championship football match: once the final matchup has been determined, fans of both teams begin *scooping up* the tickets. But the term *scoop out* is not used to describe when no more tickets are available; no one would say:

> The tickets are all scooped out. [*incorrect*]

or:

> The tickets haven't been scooped out yet. [*incorrect*]

Instead, we would say:

> The tickets are all gone. Fans scooped them up fast!

or:

> The game has been sold out. They've all been scooped up.

Now, you *could* say it in a way similar to how you were trying to say it – **if we omitted the word "out", and included the word "all"**:

> **You can still get tickets! The tickets haven't all been scooped up yet.**

or:

> **Not all the tickets have been scooped up. A few are still available.**

Comment: Thank you so much.  Yes.  I had better include the definition.   Great eliciting by you.  You are a great teacher.  Actually I had a piece of fluff. I should have written up instead of out. By the way could you also simlipfy the part of your perevious comment and say what it means: I have yet to scoop mine up.  Does it mean : my old xbox still works.  ?

Comment: Also what do you mean by saying reserve in the sentence I would reserve it for individual.  Dear J -R I have yet to have all my doubts resolved yet! :)

Comment: _I have yet to scoop mine up_ simply means _I haven't bought mine yet_. It says **nothing** about my previous Xbox. Maybe I don't even own an old one. Maybe I own an old one, but I want the newer features of the latest version. Maybe my old one stopped working, so I need to buy a new one. Maybe I own an old one, but I want a new one for myself, so I'm going to give that old one to my kids.

Comment: That "individual" comment is hard to explain. I was trying to comment on this phrase: _They have yet to scoop it up_. The word "it" is singular; the word "they" is plural. So, _They have yet to scoop it up_ means a **group** of people has yet to by **one** item. _They have yet to scoop **them** up_ is better, but that sentence is still rather vague by itself – too many pronouns. Plus, _scoop_ is an active verb; it's awkward to talk about something **not** being scooped. Imagine I said: _They have yet to do a somersault_. That's a weird sentence, because groups of people don't usually tumble.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be going for something involving **“cleaned out”**.

> ### clean out (phrasal verb)
>
> **2.** `INFORMAL` 
> **empty a place of objects or goods, especially by stealing or buying them in large quantities**
>   *Government soldiers moved in and cleaned the village out.
>
>   The supermarkets were cleaned out by panicking shoppers.*
> <sub>Source: [Definition of “clean out” from the online English dictionary from Macmillan Publishers Limited](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/clean-out)</sub>

So I'd phrase it more like:

> They haven't been cleaned out yet.

As the definition notes, this is an informal usage. To express this concept more formally, I'd say:

> Customers have yet to deplete the supply.

---

There's also the concept of “scoop **up**”

> ### scoop up (phrasal verb)
>
> **2.** `INFORMAL` 
> **to get something, usually something good or valuable, before someone else gets it**
>   *People arriving early scooped up fantastic bargains.*
> <sub>Source: [Definition of “scoop up” from the online English dictionary from Macmillan Publishers Limited](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/scoop-up)</sub>

This does connote an urgency in the action. Such a phrase might be:

> They haven't all been scooped up yet.

Or:

> You can still scoop one up.

You could even combine these two:

> Scoop one up before stores are cleaned out!

Comment: I don't really like "exhaust the supply," but I love the rest of the answer. +1

Comment: @J.R. I struggled with that part and would happily substitute a suggested alternative.

Comment: I'd happily suggest an alternative, but I'm struggling with that, too. :^)

Comment: @J.R. One of the things this place has taught me is how important context is to how I phrase things. It's really hard to know what I'd say without knowing who I'd be talking to and what we'd be talking about.

Comment: We often use *wiped out*:  I went to get a new Xbox but they were *wiped out*.

Comment: For formal maybe:  Supplies have not yet been depleted.

Comment: Bravo! I wish I could upvote again, now that you've added the part about _scoop up_!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this has actually been answered properly yet.

"They have to yet scooped it out."

can most simply be rewritten as

"They have yet to scoop it (all) out."

The addition of "all" suggests completion. Without it, it suggests that they might not yet have started.